# What is the best way to specify traits for &I type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have the next code (It compiles and works perfectly):

```
pub fn new<I: Into<PathBuf> + AsRef<Path>>(
        modpack_path: &I,
        destination: &I,
    ) -> Result<Self, ModpackError> {
        let modpack = RinthDownloader::load_pack(modpack_path)?;
        let (links, names) = RinthDownloader::get_data(&modpack);

        let destination = destination.as_ref().to_owned();

        if !destination.join("mods").exists() {
            std::fs::create_dir(destination.join("mods"))
                .map_err(|_| ModpackError::CantCreateDir)?;
        }

        if !destination.join("config").exists() {
            std::fs::create_dir(destination.join("config"))
                .map_err(|_| ModpackError::CantCreateDir)?;
        }

        Ok(RinthDownloader {
            gen_downloader: Downloader2::new(
                links.into(),
                names,
                destination.into(),
                RinthRequester::new(),
            ),
            modpack,
        })
    }
```

I want a reference to a type that can be converted to PathBuf with .into() and also want this same type to be converted to a Path when I used a reference ( &I ).

Am I doing it the right way or am I doing it wrong ?

I tried the code above and it worked fine but i want to know if I am doing it the right way and also the idiomatic way.

Comment: Where are you using the `Into<PathBuf>`?

Comment: Oh man you are right I don't need Into<PathBuf> in order to do `to_owned()`. Thanks you for making me realize that. Also, is it ok AsRef<Path> ? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `Into<PathBuf>` as you don't need it.

Also, the convention is to take `impl AsRef<Path>`, not `&impl AsRef<Path>` like you're doing (see e.g. many functions in [`std::fs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/)). This way, you can pass both references like `&Path` and `&str`, and also owned types such as `PathBuf` and `String` without needing to take a reference to them.